# Making a function that repeats across view controllers DRY

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a function that i use across my view controllers. Where is the best place to put this such that i do not repeat this across these controllers?

```
-(void)addNewQuestion
{
    AddNewQuestionViewController *anqvc = [[AddNewQuestionViewController alloc]initWithTopic:self.topic];

    [anqvc setCompletionHandler:^(Question *newQuestion){
        [self.questionTableView reloadData];
    }];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:anqvc animated:YES];
    [anqvc release];
}
```

Comment: @marek-sebera - possible, but that seems really suboptimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should implement the [observer-pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

somewhere in your app you have the model: your questions and each ViewController whoch need lists all questions should observe that list in your model. If something changes in your model: for instance adding a new question, all observers will be notified.

In obj-c you can use [Key-Value-Observing](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) for that.

So each VC which lists your data in a tableview you can call `[self.tableView reloadData]`

Or even better: create a new class which only implements the `DataSource` and use in all tableViews the same DataSource.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a bunch of classes with common same state (a questionTableView) and behavior (addNewQuestion) that sounds like a great time to introduce a common base class for them to all inherit from.

Comment: yes, but there are enough differences between them such that i think that a base class might just make things worse. but good suggestion!